# Unity3D RayCasting in 4 directions only

Tags: unity-game-engine, raycasting

I am trying to create a maze game where the player can move only when it can see a sweet.

Currently the raycast is searching in every direction (360 degrees) **But I only want the raycast to look directly Up,Left,Down,Right (instead of 360 degrees)**... This way the player can only move when a sweet is placed in direct line of sight.

```
public function setTargetSweet(target:GameObject)
{
    too = target.transform.position;
    targetSweet = target;

    var fwd = too - transform.position;

    Debug.Log("Setting target sweet: " + target.name);
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, fwd, Color.red, 5f);

    Physics.Raycast (transform.position, fwd, hit);

    if ( hit.collider.tag == "MoveToSweet") {
        print ("Can See Sweet");
        gotoSweet = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log(hit.collider.name);
        Debug.Log(hit.collider.tag);
        gotoSweet = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing ray casts in the direction of any sweet every time. You want four calls like `Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.forward, hit)` and check the hit between calls.